# How to concatenate two pairs of columns by name with shifting rows, in a dataframe with multiple column pairs

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

**I have this dataframe:**

```
     id    a1    a2    b1    b2    c1    c2
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    83    33    55    33    85    86
2     2    37     0    60    98    51     0
3     3    97    71    85     8    44    40
4     4    51     6    43    15    55    57
5     5    28    53    62    73    70     9
```

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:5, a1 = c(83L, 37L, 97L, 51L, 28L), a2 = c(33L, 
0L, 71L, 6L, 53L), b1 = c(55L, 60L, 85L, 43L, 62L), b2 = c(33L, 
98L, 8L, 15L, 73L), c1 = c(85L, 51L, 44L, 55L, 70L), c2 = c(86L, 
0L, 40L, 57L, 9L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**I want to:**
Combine columns with same starting character to one column by shifting each row of the second column by 1 down and naming the new column with the character of the two columns.

**My desired output:**

```
      id     a     b     c
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1    83    55    85
 2     1    33    33    86
 3     2    37    60    51
 4     2     0    98     0
 5     3    97    85    44
 6     3    71     8    40
 7     4    51    43    55
 8     4     6    15    57
 9     5    28    62    70
10     5    53    73     9
```

I have tried using `lag`function but I don`t know how to combine and shift columns at the same time!

To clarify a picture:
[image]

Comment: Do you only have two versions of each column name 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes. Pairs. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following solution. I also have modified your data set an added an `id` column:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(!id, names_to = c(".value", NA), names_pattern = "([[:alpha:]])(\\d)")

# A tibble: 10 x 4
      id     a     b     c
   <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1    83    55    85
 2     1    33    33    86
 3     2    37    60    51
 4     2     0    98     0
 5     3    97    85    44
 6     3    71     8    40
 7     4    51    43    55
 8     4     6    15    57
 9     5    28    62    70
10     5    53    73     9
```

Comment: This drops the `id` column.

Comment: It's weird I did not have any `id` column from the beginning. Check it now please. I added `id` variable myself.

Comment: Thank you. I have to learn still so much! Now it is clear for me!!! But the answers here helped me a lot!

Comment: You're welcome we are all learning.

Answer (score 2):

We can pivot_longer, remove the digits from name, then pivot_wider and unnest

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -id)%>%
        mutate(name=str_remove(name, '[0-9]'))%>%
        pivot_wider(names_from = name)%>%
        unnest(everything())

# A tibble: 10 x 4
      id     a     b     c
   <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1    83    55    85
 2     1    33    33    86
 3     2    37    60    51
 4     2     0    98     0
 5     3    97    85    44
 6     3    71     8    40
 7     4    51    43    55
 8     4     6    15    57
 9     5    28    62    70
10     5    53    73     9
```

Comment: Bravo my friend.

Comment: thank you anoush. I still struggle quite a lot with pivoting issues (so many parameters to pivot_* ). Yours is definitely the neat way to go.

Comment: It's ok. I once asked a similar question a couple months ago. Today I used it. I mean it's all about experience in my opinion and from now on you could use all that is mentioned here for future questions. However, your solution is very good too.

Answer (score 2):

Doing it as a `pivot_longer()`, then `pivot_wider()` is easier to read, but @Anoushiravan R's answer to more direct

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>% # Add the id column
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% # Make long
  mutate(order = str_sub(name, -1), name = str_sub(name, 1, 1)) %>% # Breakout the name column
  pivot_wider(names_from = name) %>% # Make wide again
  select(-order) # Drop the ordering column
```

Answer (score 2):

I think ANoushiravan's solution is the tidiest way to do it. We could also use {dplyover} (disclaimer) for this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(across2(ends_with("1"),
                    ends_with("2"),
                    ~ c(.x,.y),
                    .names = "{pre}"),
            )
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'id'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.

#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [5]
#>       id     a     b     c
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     1    83    55    85
#>  2     1    33    33    86
#>  3     2    37    60    51
#>  4     2     0    98     0
#>  5     3    97    85    44
#>  6     3    71     8    40
#>  7     4    51    43    55
#>  8     4     6    15    57
#>  9     5    28    62    70
#> 10     5    53    73     9
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>